# function in recipe not overridden

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I want to override a function in a recipe (bb) that inherits from a bbclass, but it doesn't work -- the function from the bbclass (superclass) is executed instead of the new one.

Here is an minimal (non-)working example.

Class:

```
# myclass.bbclass

do_compile() {
    echo MyClass
}
```

Recipe:

```
# myrecipe.bb

do_compile() {
    echo MyRecipe
}

inherit myclass
```

After I compile the recipe, the log file looks like this:

```
$ cat temp/log.do_compile
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
MyClass
DEBUG: Shell function do_compile finished
```

Why doesn't overriding of `do_compile` work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The position of `inherit` in the recipe file is important. If you put it in the beginning of the file (before the function `do_compile` is defined in the (subclass) recipe), it works.

Recipe:

```
# myrecipe.bb

inherit myclass

do_compile() {
    echo MyRecipe
}
```

After compiling the recipe the log file looks like this:

```
$ cat temp/log.do_compile
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
MyRecipe
DEBUG: Shell function do_compile finished
```